# Sed range problem if the last pattern is not met

Tags: sed, regular-expression, date

I am doing a range search with sed. I want to parse the log data from the date and time `2016-09-29 01:00` to `2016-09-29 01:30`. That is why I have been using the following command,

```
$ sed -n '/2016-09-29 01:/,/2016-09-29 01:30:.*$/p'
```

But problem is if 1:30 is not available in log then it returns all the logs to the end.

So how can work with this so that if `1:30` doesn't exist it will go to the just next record not till end.

Things to consider: Logs contains **stack trace** so lines contain stack trace doesn't start with the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so strange. `sed` is a **s**tream **ed**itor, it processes lines as they come. A range like `/a/,/b/` means the lines are selected as soon as `a` is found, and no-longer selected after `b` is found. If `b` is never found, it never stops selecting lines.

Here, you should rather use `awk` instead. Assuming those timestamps are at the beginning of the line:

```
awk '$0 >= "2016-09-29 01:" && $0 < "2016-09-29 01:30"'
```

Note that it will only select lines that have a timestamp in the range, so would excludes lines that don't have a timestamp even if they are between lines that have timestamps in the range.

Another approach to work around that would be:

```
awk -v start='2016-09-29 01:' -v end='2016-09-29 01:30' '
  $0 >= start && $0 <= end, /^[0-9]{4}([ :-][0-9]{2}){5}/ && $0 >= end'
```

That is use a range like in `sed`, but enter the range on the first line that is between the 2 dates, and leave it only when we find a line with a timestamp that is greater than the end date.

Comment: Worked like charm. But then I saw that it doesn't include stack traces.

Comment: @muhammad, see edit.