# Output log lines between startTime and endTime

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cut

Given I have log file `app.log` with contents:

```
2018-08-29 07:43:17.123-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound request was sent.


2018-08-29 07:43:17.456-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound response was received.


2018-08-29 07:44:18.789-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound request was sent.


2018-08-29 07:44:18.779-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound response was received.


2018-08-29 07:45:19.433-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound request was sent.


2018-08-29 07:45:19.998-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound response was received.


2018-08-29 07:46:20.658-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound request was sent.


2018-08-29 07:46:20.774-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound response was received.
```

I'd like to get log lines between timestamp range I specify as arguments.

Please note, that log line is not just 1 line starting with timestamp. There is additional information after that line until there is next line with different timestamp.

So in our example:

```
2018-08-29 07:43:17.123-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound request was sent.
```

is 1 log line.

So, I'd like to execute `some command 2018-08-29 07:44:00.000 2018-08-29 07:46:00.000 app.log` what will return

```
2018-08-29 07:44:18.789-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound request was sent.


2018-08-29 07:44:18.779-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound response was received.


2018-08-29 07:45:19.433-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound request was sent.


2018-08-29 07:45:19.998-0500 CDT [osb_02] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO -
 [OSB Tracing] Outbound response was received.
```

Also note, arguments are not necessarily present in log file.

Comment: See [this very similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465477/265461).

Answer (score 0):

`sed '1,/pattern1/d;/pattern2/,$d' app.log` should do the trick

if you wanted it as a script to run the way you mention, then a function in your ~/.bashrc like the below should do:

```
time_log() {
    pattern1=$1
    pattern2=$2
    file=$3
    sed "1,/$pattern1/d;/$pattern2/,$d" "$file"
}
```

then you can run:

`time_log "2018-08-29 07:44:" "2018-08-29 07:46:" app.log`

#### edit:

*removed uneccessary `cat`*

To include the first line, the easiest way would just to be `grep` the first line before running the `sed`:

```
time_log() {
    pattern1=$1
    pattern2=$2
    file=$3
    grep "$pattern1" "$file"
    sed "1,/$pattern1/d;/$pattern2/,$d" "$file"
}
```

Though there is probably a better way of doing this with `sed` if any sed masters would like to chime in.

Comment: the command doesn't include first timestamp line.. how can it be changed so that it does so?

Comment: please see my updated answer :)

Comment: it's kind of a hack.. I would like to call only one command.. it might be that `awk` will be more useful in this scenario